# REPLACE non-numeric values and MATCH in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `code` LIKE 'PR-SM' AND number = '45'
```

However in some instances the number can be `PR45` which will then fail. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `code` LIKE 'PR-SM' AND CAST(number as unsigned) = '45'

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `code` LIKE 'PR-SM' AND CONVERT(number as unsigned) = '45'

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `code` LIKE 'PR-SM' AND number LIKE '%45'
```

`LIKE %` will not work as it also picks up 145.

`REGEXP_REPLACE` also does not work as I am on `MySQL 5.7`

This is needed for my API, because of my setup I need to be able to do it in the where clause.

Sample Table:

```
+--------------------------+
| code       | number      |
+--------------------------+
| PR-SM      |  PR45       |
+--------------------------+
| PR-SM      |  PR145      |
+--------------------------+
| XYZ        |  177        |
+--------------------------+
| XYZ        |  81         |
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: You jumped into the query without giving any sample data or a proper problem statement.  Please include these.

Comment: I've added a sample table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are not using MySQL 8+, which means you won't have access to the newer regex functions, on 5.7 `REGEXP` should still be available:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE code = 'PR-SM' AND number REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])45([^0-9]|$)';
```

### Demo

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
(^|[^0-9])  match the start of the input OR a non digit
45          match the number 45
([^0-9]|$)  match the end of the input OR a non digit
```